# How can use AnimatedSize child of AnimatedPositioned in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, animation

I want to use AnimatedSize, in child of AnimatedPositioned but i get the exception.

this is my code :

```
AnimatedPositioned(
  duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
  curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
  top: isProfileSelected ? 100 : 0,
  child: Transform.translate(
    offset:
     Offset(isProfileSelected ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 - 53 :MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 - 38, 90 / 2),
    child: AnimatedSize(
      curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
      child: isProfileSelected ? SizedBox(
        width: 106.0,
        child: circleAvatar(106, 106),
      ) : SizedBox(
        width: 76.0,
        child: circleAvatar(76, 76),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: try adding a duration to `AnimatedSize`

Comment: can you add the the exception that your are getting?

Comment: This exception (The following assertion was thrown building Positioned(top: 100.0):
'package:flutter/src/rendering/animated_size.dart': Failed assertion: line 86 pos 15: 'vsync != null': is not true.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to your class state

```
class _MyWidgetState extends State<_MyWidget> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
    .............
  AnimatedPositioned(
    duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
    curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
    top: isProfileSelected ? 100 : 0,
    child: Transform.translate(
    offset:
     Offset(isProfileSelected ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 - 53 :MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 - 38, 90 / 2),
    child: AnimatedSize(
      vsync: this, //This must be required
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200), //Duration is also required
      curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
      child: isProfileSelected ? SizedBox(
        width: 106.0,
        child: circleAvatar(106, 106),
      ) : SizedBox(
        width: 76.0,
        child: circleAvatar(76, 76),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
......................
```

}